# JQuery logic question

Tags: jquery

How can I achieve the following affect with JQuery when I place my mouse over an image as in the following link http://www.360internetservices.com/templates.php?cPage=2

Comment: At Stackoverflow, its nice to see you at least tried: "Jquery and mouse over" in google would have given you at least 50% of the answer.

Comment: Well mostly haters on SO. Thanks to everyone who answered my question and even more thanks to the haters who justify everything I do.

Comment: You don't try, and you don't upvote or respond to any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You would put the full image within an attribute of the thumbnail, for instance `data-full`. Then you would bind a mouseover event to the thumbnail that will place the image from `data-full` within a target div and remove it again on mouseout.

Or you could place the images there in advance, and just bind a mouseover event to the thumbnail that will `show()` the related full image.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#mysmallimage' ).mouseover( function () {

    $( '#mybigimage' ).toggle();

});
```

Assuming your big images are first hidden with `display:none` via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethink like this...

```
<img src="thumb-1.jpg" id="img_1"/>

<img id="bg_1">
```

JQuery

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img_1") .mouseover(function() {$('#bg_1').attr('src','large-1.jpg');}
$("img_1") .mouseout(function() {$('#bg_1').attr('src','');}
        }) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery method of show & hide...

use onmouseover & onmouseout event of image and set them to javascript functions with the argument taking pic name or path to show or hide,and use jQuery show & hide method...